# Customer pays in EUR and I receive bitcoin anonymously

Tags: privacy, business

I run a small business, and up to now I have always demanded to be paid in cash for my services.

I want to allow my customers to pay electronically through wire transfer, while remaining anonymous myself.

Is there a service which acts as a flexible always-ready EUR-to-bitcoin converter, such that my customers can pay electronically to a bank account owned by that service, whereafter an equivalent amount of bitcoin are transferred to me?

Comment: This is basically the definition of facilitating money laundering. If the funds were stolen, how would the service get the money back from you? If you're a terrorist, how would the service know?

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think there are any good services that will allow customers to pay with fiat and have you receive Bitcoin even if you were okay with completing KYC, but regardless, no legitimate fiat payment processor will allow you to stay anonymous.